# XML Schema Reference and Types Not Declared

Tags: xml, xsd, envelope

I'm a novice to schema construction and am having problems understanding how namespace references should work.  I work with an application that is similar to BizTalk and performs a de-envelop operation on the following schemas.  I'm not sure if this is a general error, but this is the error I get:

Error

```
XmlSchemaValidationException, Type 'http://Wheelhouse/Property:PropertyType' is not declared. :
```

Property Definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Wheelhouse/Property" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Wheelhouse/Property" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Property" type="PropertyType" />
  <xs:complexType name="PropertyType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Listing_Number" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Status" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Property List Definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="blueintegrator://Wheelhouse/PropertyDefinition__4f3f265569d54e9fa898eba835502c6a_" namespace="http://Wheelhouse/Property" />
  <xs:element xmlns="http://Wheelhouse/Property" name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Property" type="PropertyType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not working has to do with the URI scheme (blueintegrator) in the schemaLocation attribute. Most likely your tool that you're using to consume the XSDs doesn't understand that URI, hence it cannot load the XSD which contains the definition of the `http://Wheelhouse/Property:PropertyType` type.

For "normal" tools, if you change the value of that attribute to something else (for example, if you put both files in the same folder then replace the entire schemaLocation value with the name of the file) you'll see that the schemas are perfectly valid.